# How do I filter a LINQ query so it returns only records with the maximum date, yet still get child and grand-child related tables?

Tags: c#, linq

I've got a LINQ query which is returning the values I want from a Person table, two related child tables (Agency and PersonnelCertifications) and a related grand-child table (CertificationType). This is working fine. Here is the LINQ query so far (I'm using .NET 4.5.2 and EF 6):

```cs
using (var ctx = new AppEntities())
{
    People = ctx.People.AsNoTracking().Where(p => p.Inactive == false)
        .Include(p => p.Agency)
        .Include(p => p.PersonnelCertifications.Select(pc => pc.CertificationType))
        .Where(p => p.PersonnelCertifications.Any(pc => pc.CertificationType.CertType == "Operator"))
        .OrderBy(p => p.LastName)
        .ThenBy(p => p.FirstName)
        .ToList();
}
```

(People is of type list of Person.) However, I now have a new requirement. The PersonnelCertifications table has a column named `CertExpirationDate`. It's possible that there could be 3 PersonnelCertifications records related to a person. For example, the oldest could be September 12, 2015. The next one could be April 20, 2021. The last one could be February 12, 2022 for some person. When running the query I only want the PersonnelCertifications record for February 12, 2022. How do I modify the above LINQ query so that I get the maximum CertExpirationDate of PersonnelCertifications for each person?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be just to load all `PersonnelCertifications` for a `Person` from the database and then filter out the most recent one in the memory i.e.

```
foreach(person in People) {
   person.PersonnelCertifications = person.PersonnelCertifications.Where(pc => pc.CertExpirationDate == person.PersonnelCertifications.Max(pc => pc.CertExpirationDate ) )
}
```

the other option would be to project the entities into a custom DTO class. This way you don't need to load the additional `PersonnelCertifications` from the database only the most recent one i.e.

```
public class PersonViewModel {
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public string Age {get; set;}
   public IEnumerable<PersonalCertificationViewModel> PersonnelCertifications         {get; set;}
}


public class PersonalCertificationViewModel {
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public DateTime ExpirationDate {get; set;}
}

People = ctx.People.AsNoTracking().Where(p => p.Inactive == false)
    .Include(p => p.Agency)
    .Include(p => p.PersonnelCertifications.Select(pc => pc.CertificationType))
    .Where(p => p.PersonnelCertifications.Any(pc => pc.CertificationType.CertType == "Operator"))
    .OrderBy(p => p.LastName)
    .ThenBy(p => p.FirstName)
    .Select(p => new PersonViewModel {
                   Name = p.Name,
                   Age = p.Age,
                   PersonnelCertifications = p.PersonnelCertifications.Where(pc => pc.CertExpirationDate == p.PersonnelCertifications.Max(pc => pc.CertExpirationDate))
                                 .Select(pc => new PersonnelCertifications { Name = pc.Name, ExpirationDate = pc.ExpirationDate })
    }).ToList()
```

Comment: Anton, I decided to go with the simple solution you gave at first. Just an FYI, I found that I had to use `ToList()` to assign the filtered value to `person.PersonnelCertifications`.